# How to implement PeriodicWorkRequest chain?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I study Android WorkManager, and fond one problem.

I have 2 Works, first of them fetch some data from server and second preload resources (depends on result of first work). I need doing this chains one time per hour.

I need something like:

```
workManager.beginWith(work1).then(work2)
```

But in WorkManger API I found chain only for OneTimeWorkRequest.

Comment: did you find out the way to do periodic work request in  chain?

Comment: No, but for this case I use periodic worker which start chain of OneTimeWorkRequests, looks ugly, but working for me

Answer (score 6):

You cannot chain `PeriodicWorkRequest`s. For your use-case you might consider using a `OneTimeWorkRequest` with a `Worker` that enqueues a copy of itself at the end of `doWork()` with an initial delay (to simulate periodicity).

That way you can still do chaining. I would tag all work requests consistently so you can `getWorkInfosByTagLiveData()` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Promoting Andrew's comment into an answer:

Google's had an open ticket to add this functionality
(see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111234229)).

Google's official solution there was to create a periodic work request with an "chain initiation" worker, in that worker's doWork() define and enqueue a chain of one-time work requests.

Answer (score 0):

I was able do to it through creating a simple `PeriodicWorkRequest` with its `doWork()` implements the following

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    ...
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).beginWith(oneTimeWork1).then(oneTimeWork2).enqueue()
    Result.success()
}
```

Not ideal but this way it triggers the chain at its periodic interval